# Do GraalVM JavaScript's JS-to-Java object conversions contain type information?

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm, graaljs

To mimic on GraalVM JavaScript some of Node's functions under `util.types`, I turned to Java functions that I can access through `Java.type` or the Java package global variables. GraalVM's has internal functions like `JSProxy.isJSProxy` and `JSSet.isJSSet` that do this. I made them accessible by marking them as a exported, recompiled, and tested them (I accessed them with, e.g., `Java.type("com.oracle.truffle.js.builtins.runtime.JSProxy").isJSProxy`).

As I found out, GraalVM JavaScript's internal functions are useless to me. For example, `JSProxy.isJSProxy` only returns `true` if it is passed an instance of `JSProxyObject`. Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/20/docs/reference-manual/js/JavaInteroperability/) says that

> JavaScript objects are exposed to Java code as instances of `com.oracle.truffle.api.interop.java.TruffleMap`. This class implements Java’s Map interface.

TruffleMap doesn't appear in the source code of [GraalVM JavaScript](https://github.com/oracle/graaljs) and only appears once in the source code of [GraalVM](https://github.com/oracle/graal), so it's likely deprecated, but that's besides the point because the representation method is probably the same.

Whatever the external Java-side representation of JS objects is right now, does it contain information about what the object's type on the JavaScript side is? Can I determine if it's a JS proxy? Can I determine if it's a `Set` object? (And so on for native JavaScript object types.)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your question is quite confusing to me, but are you just looking for the `instanceof` operator?

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.proxy.*;

public class Test {
    public static class MyClass {
        public int id = 42;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try (Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowAllAccess(true).build()) {
            context.getBindings("js").putMember("javaObj", new MyClass());
            boolean valid = context
              .eval("js", "javaObj instanceof Java.type('Test$MyClass')")
              .asBoolean();
            assert valid;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not even close. Any object passed from JavaScript to Java will converted to the same wrapper class.

Comment: Maybe an example would make your question more clear.